# how to censor data point labels (annotations) if label text overlaps in the plot when using ggraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

I am attempting to plot some data using `ggraph`. The style is a `circular` `partition` plot. I have numerous plots/graphs. Each has a different density of dendritic branching. Nodes on the graph are labeled with `geom_node_text(aes(label = labelText))`. I know I can use scaling or text size to adjust effective font point. However, I would like to hold font point constant and just censor labels (i.e., assign label value to be something like `" "`) for dense regions of each graph, given some density threshold parameter. How could this be done? For instance, is there a way to extract the `x, y` coordinates of text labels such that a density function can be computed over the plot area?

Comment: Please share some code and reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This falls under the heading of [RTFM](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/ggraph/html/geom_node_text.html).

> `check_overlap`
> If TRUE, text that overlaps previous text in the same layer will not be plotted. check_overlap happens at draw time and in the order of the data. Therefore data should be arranged by the label column before calling geom_label() or geom_text().

Comment: I think it might also fall into the “failure to search” category. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html